# Min/Max Heap implementation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, min-heap, max-heap

This is my implementation of a MinHeap and MaxHeap in python. This uses a comparator to reverse the sequence of storage in the MaxHeap

```
import heapq


class MinHeap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.heap = []

    def push(self, item):
        heapq.heappush(self.heap, item)

    def pop(self):
        return heapq.heappop(self.heap)

    def peek(self):
        return self.heap[0]

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.heap[item]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.heap)


class MaxHeap(MinHeap):
    def push(self, item):
        heapq.heappush(self.heap, Comparator(item))

    def pop(self):
        return heapq.heappop(self.heap)

    def peek(self):
        return self.heap[0]

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.heap[i].val


class Comparator:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.val > other

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.val == other




if __name__ == '__main__':
    max_heap = MaxHeap()
    max_heap.push(12)
    max_heap.push(3)
    max_heap.push(17)
    print(max_heap.pop())
```

The MinHeap seems to work fine, however the MaxHeap throw up the following error.

```
<__main__.Comparator object at 0x10a5c1080>
```

I don't quite seem to understand what am I doing wrong here. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: But the item stored in the list is a comparator which is weird.

Comment: @MelissaStewart your class needs [`total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering)

Comment: @MelissaStewart I made a mistake with the 6 comparison methods at the end of my answer. But they've been fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added `__repr__` and `__gt__` methods to your `Comparator` class, so the code now runs, and the `Comparator` instances display their `val` when printed.

The important thing is to get those comparison methods to do the comparisons correctly between two `Comparator` instances.

You'll notice that I've eliminated most of the methods from `MaxHeap`. They aren't needed because the methods inherited from `MinHeap` work ok. You may wish to restore this one to `MaxHeap`

```
def __getitem__(self, i):
    return self.heap[i].val
```

depending on how you intend to use `MaxHeap`.

```
import heapq

class MinHeap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.heap = []

    def push(self, item):
        heapq.heappush(self.heap, item)

    def pop(self):
        return heapq.heappop(self.heap)

    def peek(self):
        return self.heap[0]

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.heap[item]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.heap)

class MaxHeap(MinHeap):
    def push(self, item):
        heapq.heappush(self.heap, Comparator(item))

class Comparator:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.val > other.val

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.val == other.val

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.val)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    max_heap = MaxHeap()
    max_heap.push(12)
    max_heap.push(3)
    max_heap.push(17)

    while True:
        try:
            print(max_heap.pop())
        except IndexError:
            # The heap's empty, bail out
            break
```

**output**

```
17
12
3
```

It's probably a Good Idea to give `Comparator` the full set of rich comparison methods. They aren't needed to make the above code work, but they will make the `Comparator` instances more flexible. So in case you want them, here they are:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.val > other.val

def __le__(self, other):
    return self.val >= other.val

def __gt__(self, other):
    return self.val < other.val

def __ge__(self, other):
    return self.val <= other.val

def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.val == other.val

def __ne__(self, other):
    return self.val != other.val
```